# I am trying to store the csv file into an array and then compare each cell by storing it in a temp array and extract into a 1d array or a vector in C#

Tags: c#

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"data/ap4.csv");
var pdData = new List<string[]>();

using (var stream_r = new StreamReader(@ap4.csv))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = stream_r.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string[] row = line.Split(',');
        pdData.Add(row);
    }
}
int k = 0;
string[][] temp = pdData.ToArray();

var se_state = new string[2000];

for(int i = 1; i< rowlength;i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j< totalcols; j++)
    {
      if(temp[i][j] != "0" && temp[i][j] != se_state[k])
        {
            k++;
            se_state[k] = temp[i][j];

        }
    }
}
```

The error i get is :
Index was outside the bounds of the array at the if loop , i think the se_state is out of bounds exception. I am unable to check the element of the temp array with another array which is 1-dimensional

Comment: Where are you setting `rowlength` and `totalcols`?

Comment: `var se_state = new string[]{ };` creates a zero length array.

Comment: this is how i set the row and col length :   var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"data/ap4.csv");
            var totalcols = lines[0].Split(',').Length;
            var rowlength = lines.Count();

Comment: @Johnny, do i need to assign it to the first element of temp to se_state

Comment: As @Johnny mentioned, you need to specify the size of the array upfront. Arrays have a fixed size so you need to allocate the required space or grow the array manually as needed.

Comment: @momar thanks for your comments , i did initalise the string array so it goes into the loop and then i get the same "system out of bounds exception for the below line                                                                                  se_state[k] = temp[i][j];

Comment: Thanks for your comments i managed to fix the problem by increasing the array size